# Parallelize processes on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, parallel-processing, xargs

I want to run some processes in parallel, I'd like to do for examle:

```
php scan.php 1.pdf > 1.txt & php scan.php 2.pdf > 2.txt & php scan.php 3.pdf > 3.txt
```

but the problem is to call it automatically where files, like 1.pdf, 2.pdf... are listed in directory.

If I use

```
find inprogress-gp/ -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec basename {} \; | xargs -n1 php scan.php
```

then I can call

```
php scan.php 1.pdf
php scan.php 2.pdf
php scan.php 3.pdf
....
```

Any clue how to solve the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to a GNU Parallel answer:

```
parallel 'php scan.php {} > {.}.txt' ::: *.pdf
```

Or, if your PDF files are in subdirectories:

```
find . -name \*.pdf | parallel 'php {} > {.}.txt'
```

The following demonstrates that jobs are started immediately there  is a job slot available, and so, using just 2 cores, it does the 10 second sleep and 5 further sleeps of 2 seconds each, all in 10 seconds:

```
parallel --line-buffer -j 2 'echo Job {#} starting; sleep {}; echo Job {#} done' ::: 10 2 2 2 2 2
Job 1 starting
Job 2 starting
Job 2 done
Job 3 starting
Job 3 done
Job 4 starting
Job 4 done
Job 5 starting
Job 5 done
Job 6 starting
Job 1 done
Job 6 done
```

Comment: hmm, looks promising, but if I have 1000+ pdf-s in folder, how to set maximums parallel processes?

Comment: If you have 8 CPU cores, it will run 8 at a time. If you want more, say 32, just use `parallel -j 32` or if you want 2, use `parallel -j 2`.

Comment: It is actually *better* than a maximum, it is really the number it keeps running at any one time, so if one job takes hours it will keep 7 other smaller jobs running all the time.

Comment: It works, thanks! :) Would be better if next process could start right after previous, without waiting all paraller tasks for execution. But this is better any way. :)

Comment: It does work that way - I have added an example to clarify. Glad it works well for you - good luck with your project!